# Exception when trying to run tracemetrics with ns3

Tags: java, protocols

I have macOS Catalina 10.15.7

java version "15.0.1" 2020-10-20

Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 15.0.1+9-18)

I need to compare the performance between different protocols using ns3

I have run Manet-routing-compare.cc successfully
Then I download TraceMetrics and run
java -jar tracemetrics.jar

Then I choose the trace file and try to analyze it

The analysing process is 0% and I got this error:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.lang.Integer.intValue()" because the return value of "java.util.HashMap.get(Object)" is null
at analyzer.controller.LineParser.getWifiMacLength(LineParser.java:791)
```

Please help me

Answer (score 0):

If the tracemetrics version is 1.4.0, the analysing process is 0% always. Download tracemetrics 1.3.0 and it will be ok.